Should a stealth check be opposed by vigilance or perception when opposition is not actively searching?
In our Edge of the Empire campaign, we are often wondering how to deal with a situation where a character is attempting to use Stealth to avoid being detected by someone who is not actively searching for them. We are unsure whether the Stealth check should be opposed by the other character's Vigilance or Perception.
From the Core rulebook we just get that

Stealth checks are typically opposed by Perception, based upon whether the opponent is passively or actively searching for the hidden character.

Can vigilance be used in the given situation to determine the difficulty of the check?

Nothing in the rules suggests that Vigilance should ever be used for opposing a Stealth check. As the passage of the rules you quoted says, usually Perception is used. The alternative would be for the Game Master to set a fixed difficulty for the check, if the challenge has more to do with the environment than the sensitivity of a potential observer's senses.
Vigilance is almost exclusively used for initiative when you're not expecting a fight in advance (e.g. you're being ambushed or betrayed).
That said, Vigilance is a pretty weak skill in general, so adding a new function to it as a house rule would probably not unbalance anything. It might make balance better than the rules as written.
